# How can we import to Suppression list in the Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

Can we import subscribers to the suppression list using an excel spreadsheet? If not, what are the ways to import to suppression list, and do we need to activate anything for this?

I checked the documentation and it seems like it should be possible, but I do not see the option of import activity in the menu that is specified.

> 1. Click the Interactions tab on the navigation bar.
> 2. Click Activities.
> 3. Click Import.

Comment: Is this related to ExactTarget?

Comment: Yes this is related to exact target

Comment: Why is this not being answered till now? No answers were given to this by ET support as we'll. Does ET support suppression list?

Comment: I've just done a quick search and it was not hard to find the documentation that explains how to do this. On SFSE it's generally expected that you've researched and gotten stuck before posting, though it seems odd that support didn't respond. Normally this question would be closed but I'm going to keep it open on the off chance that others have similar issues finding the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[Ok so the documentation on Suppression Lists](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/) does have a section on importing:

> **How to Import into a Suppression List**
>
> Refer to Import Activity for information on importing into a
>   suppression list. You can import opt-out subscribers collected out of
>   the Email application. If a subscriber does not exist in the system,
>   the subscriber is added as Active, and then only Opted-out at the
>   suppression list level. The suppression list level is the list to
>   which they were imported. Importing into a suppression list is
>   supported for Enterprise 2.0 only at this time.
>
> Subscriber attributes are not supported for suppression list imports.
>   The system only supports the following:
>
> - Email Address
> - Subscriber Key (If enabled in your account)
> - Status (active or unsubscribed)
> - Reason (The unsubscribe/opt-out reason)

[The full details of importing are too long to list here but you can find them on the linked page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/), and they do support both comma and tab delimted files meaning you can use data from Excel.

Comment: But I do not see the option of import activity in the menu that is specified in the documentation. Do I need to do something for this? This is what I wanted to know from support but no body answered and instead directed me to stack exchange

Comment: Ok, so that's what you needed to write in your question :)

Comment: No this I found out now when I read the Import activity section of the documentation

Comment: The thing that confused me was that in normal list I could go and do an import. there is an option for it but in Supression List I did not see such option that is when I asked this question. Now after I saw the documentation I did not see the option as mentioned in the documentation. Is this some feature that we need to activate?